# Calculating the angle an object has to be launched at with simulated drag

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, drag

I’m trying to calculate the angle(s) a projectile has to be launched at in a game that has a simulated drag which reduces the velocity by 2.5% of the current velocity per tick (25 milliseconds). This is independent from it’s shape and mass.

I'm given initial speed, distance and gravity. I know that theta is:

[image: Formula for launch angles]

Where $v$ is the initial velocity, $x$ the distance and $y$ the initial height.

And I figured that the function of velocity for an object after it’s launched is exponentially decaying so I came up with this function:

[image: Function for Velocity]

Where v_0 is the initial speed, 2.5 is the percentage and 0.025 the tick rate.

Is there a way to account for this drag in the original formula or is there a different one? So far I only found formulas for linear drag but I'm not sure how I would incorporate this as this drag isn’t dependent on an objects mass and terminal velocity.

Comment: Where is the drag coefficient in your equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is modeling an object with "linear drag".  Since the rate at which the velocity decreases is proportional to the velocity itself, we can write
$$
\frac{\Delta v_x}{\Delta t} = - \frac{0.025 v_x}{25 \text{ ms}} = - \alpha v_x
$$
(more or less), with $\alpha = 10 \text{ s}^{-1}$. A similar equation holds for $v_y$, but with the gravitational acceleration of $-g$ factored in.

Since the drag is linear, it is possible to solve exactly for the position and the velocity as a function of time;  I did so in my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/514194/projectile-motion-variation-of-the-equation-of-the-trajectory-and-motion-introd/514202#514202).  However, finding a "range equation" is a much harder;  you would have to find the time $t$ of the landing of the object and then figure out the value of $x$ at that time, which I don't think is actually doable algebraically (since $y(t)$ is transcendental in $t$.)  Trying to find a nice function for $\theta$ as a function of the desired range is probably a fool's errand.

The best tactic would be to solve the problem iteratively, just like the artillery officers do in the real world:  generate a trajectory, see where it lands, adjust the angle accordingly, and repeat until the answer is "close enough".