# Why are the mechanics of different axes independent of each other?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, vectors, linear-systems

Why are the mechanics of different axes independent of each other ?
Even though the question might seem absurd, but that is how physics works, is'nt it.
While solving projectile motion, why does the force, displacement, velocity, acceleration etc in $x$-axis depend only on the mechanics of $x$-axis and not the $y$-axis? Is it because that is what we observe in the practical world. Could it not be possible in any other circumstance that we apply a horizontal force on a book but it starts to move vertically.

(I have seen somewhat similar problems already but I have not been satisfied with the answers)

Comment: A review of [conservation of linear momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_law) and its origins may be enough to clear this up.

Comment: You might find [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/177828/what-makes-the-equations-of-motion-dependent-on-each-other) interesting. It’s the opposite of yours!

Comment: *While solving projectile motion, why does the force, displacement, velocity, acceleration etc in x-axis depend only on the mechanics of x-axis and not the y-axis?* Because you’re neglecting the drag force. See the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because classical mechanics has a vector structure. Because you can always break forces, displacements, momenta, etc into components with respect to some coordinate system, you can always solve the equations of classical mechanics, which are always vectorial because Newton's 2nd law is vectorial, component by component.

Now you may ask, but then why is classical mechanics like that? Ultimately we don't know and we can't know; it's outside the range of physics which can only observe how things are and then try to explain them, but never explain why they are that way and not another. After a lot of observation we came to the conclusion that a vector model is best; but you are of course right, it could easily be another way. It just isn't.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! Could you by chance share links to websites or studies or researches that have been made on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the x and y axes are normal to each other. In this case normal means the same thing as perpendicular, but normal has a broader meaning that is important in other vector spaces.

Suppose you have an object in the xy plane and you apply a force to it in the +y direction. The object accelerates in the +y direction.

Rotate the direction of the force. You get less and less acceleration in the +y direction. If you rotate far enough, the component falls to $0$ and goes to the -y direction. The angle where the component is $0$ is important. In that direction, there is no y component of acceleration.

Not coincidentally, that is the direction chosen for the x axis.

This ties in to the dot product. $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ are unit vectors along the axes. Given a vector $\vec F$, the component in the $\hat y$ direction is $\vec F \cdot \hat y$. We have carefully chosen $\hat x$ so that $\hat x \cdot \hat y = 0$. If $\vec F$ is along the x axis, then $\vec F = F \hat x$ and therefore $\vec F \cdot \hat y = 0$.

Note that by definition, two vectors $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ are normal $\iff \vec v_1 \cdot \vec v_2 = 0$

This and the fact that vector spaces are by definition linear is all you need for mechanical independence of the axes. It takes a lot of trivial math to show it. For example, a force in a given direction produces a change in momentum in that direction.

$$ \Delta \vec p = \vec F \Delta t$$

You can use this to show the x component of $\Delta p$ comes from the x component of $\vec F$.

$$ \Delta p_x\hat x + \Delta p_y\hat y = 
\Delta \vec p 
= F \Delta t 
= (F_x \hat x + F_y \hat y)\Delta t
= F_x \Delta t \hat x + F_y \Delta t \hat y
$$

Dotting both sides by $\hat x$

$$ (\Delta p_x\hat x + \Delta p_y\hat y) \cdot \hat x = 
(F_x \Delta t \hat x + F_y \Delta t \hat y) \cdot \hat x
$$

or

$$ \Delta p_x = F_x \Delta t $$