# What the difference is between Størmer Verlet and regular Verlet method?

Tags: terminology, computational-physics, algorithms

I was wondering what the difference is between the Størmer Verlet method and the regular [Verlet method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration), if there is any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My impression is that the two methods are the same, in both cases the position is updated using
$$x_{n+1}=2x_n-x_{n-1}+a_n\Delta t^2$$
with $a_n$ the acceleration.

Usually, however, I hear "Verlet integration" to be about the *velocity Verlet* method, where the velocity at the half-step is used:

1. Compute $x(t+\Delta t)=v(t)+\frac12a(t)\Delta t^2$
2. Compute $a(t+\Delta t)$ using the updated position
3. Compute $v(t+\Delta t)=v(t)+\frac12\left(a(t)+a(t+\Delta t)\right)\Delta t$

This, of course, assumes the acceleration does not depends on velocity, which would require a slight modification to the algorithm (I discuss [this here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/240475/25301)). The link Qmechanic's added to your post can provide more details to the base method.

Comment: The method was rediscovered several times, including by Störmer, and by Verlet. Sometimes it is called Newton-Störmer-Verlet, because it appeared in Newton's Principia Mathematica. Some of the historical background can be found [here](http://www.math.kit.edu/ianm3/lehre/geonumint2009s/media/gni_by_stoermer-verlet.pdf) also [doi:10.1017/S0962492902000144](https://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0962492902000144).

Comment: @LonelyProf yes, that is my understanding. In fact, the Wikipedia entry on Stormer says that he used the Verlet method for a problem and that's why it's also called the Stormer method.

Comment: And my apologies for mis-spelling Størmer, too late to correct now....

Comment: @LonelyProf I can't even get it on my cellphone keyboard, so I'm totally okay ;)... curiously, the guy's name uses a "slashed o" whereas the method uses an "umlaut o".