# Matrix Used for Orbital Motion

Tags: orbital-motion, computational-physics, celestial-mechanics

this question is by no means a new question, however previous questions have been unable to exactly answer my question. I'm attempting to obtain analytical results and then plot the results of a central field system when given the initial position and velocity of the particle. I know this is just an Initial Value Problem and I have already programmed a Runge-Kutta method, which I would hope to use, or even the scipy.linalg.solve_ivp. However, I don't know how to start properly. For my RK method, I can apply a (2,2) ndarray to my system then iterate, but I don't know what this matrix would take the form of, i.e. what would be the elements general form look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Runge Kutta 4 for orbits and Newtonian Mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/448695/)

Comment: I hadn't even thought about using RK4 method, I had programmed a RK3 method. I'll give it a look!

Comment: Would you know of any questions previously asked about using the scipy.integrate.solve_ivp function? I haven't been able to find anything yet

Comment: No, usually questions on the specific implementations are off topic, so you’d be unlikely to find one on it. You would be better off looking on [so] for that function