# Physics Simulation of a Simple Pendulum with Drag Forces

Tags: classical-mechanics, computational-physics, simulations

I am working on simulating a simple pendulum with present drag forces. My task is to use numerical methods (I am using Verlet integrator) to estimate the angle as a function of time, as well as the angular velocity and acceleration.

I am supposed to track the motion of the pendulum for 24s to measure the angle and angular velocity evolution and make a phase space diagram of these.

Even for a dt of 0.001, at 0.1 seconds I observe this:

[image]

It is worth noting that at the end of the simulation for this case, the steps taken are about 100,000.

I know that error-build up must be an issue here.

My question is, do I have to find another numerical method to estimate this oscillation that can handle this task? Or am I not using Verlet correctly?

Comment: The frequency of your simple pendulum seems to be about 300 Hz. That corresponds to a pendulum less than 3 microns long. It is tricky to build a pendulum this small. Perhaps there is some problem with your code.

Comment: Your oscillation amplitude is increasing with time. Is this what you expect? Probably you should double-check your calculation.

Comment: What are the dynamics equations you are using? And which Verlet implementation?

Comment: For quadratic drag (i.e., $F_\text{drag}\propto v^2$), you can't use straight Verlet methods, it has to be modified. See [this post of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/239621/23501)

Comment: 1. Your drag term seems to have the wrong sign. 2. Your problem seems to be at 180 degrees, i.e. vertical. 2'. Plot including 0 and using multiples of 30 or 45 degrees. 3. Show on the same plot what happens without drag, just to check.

Comment: Did you finally get the answer?  Despite the comments a few things are not clear: (1) are you using linear, quadratic, or some other drag model, (2) Why did you choose a specific integrator (why not Crank-Nicolson, RK5(4), etc), and (3) did you write the integrator from scratch or are you using Maple, Mathematica, etc.