# What is the point of half-step Verlet integration

Tags: computational-physics, integration, simulations

In the [Wikipedia article on Verlet method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration), under the Velocity Verlet method, the first algorithm proposed uses half steps:

> Calculate $\vec{v}\left(t + \tfrac12\,\Delta t\right) = \vec{v}(t) + \tfrac12\,\vec{a}(t)\,\Delta t$. 
> Calculate $\vec{x}(t + \Delta t) = \vec{x}(t) + \vec{v}\left(t + \tfrac12\,\Delta t\right)\, \Delta t$. 
> Derive $\vec{a}(t + \Delta t)$ from the interaction potential using $\vec{x}(t + \Delta t)$. 
> Calculate $\vec{v}(t + \Delta t) = \vec{v}\left(t + \tfrac12\,\Delta t\right) + \tfrac12\,\vec{a}(t + \Delta t)\Delta t$.

One sentence later it is mentioned that you may also eliminate the half steps.

I don't really get why one should use the half steps in the first place when the solution without half steps is trivially derived from the base equations:

$$\vec{x}(t + \Delta t) = \vec{x}(t) + \vec{v}(t)\, \Delta t + \frac{1}{2} \,\vec{a}(t) \Delta t^2$$
$$\vec{v}(t + \Delta t) = \vec{v}(t) + \frac{\vec{a}(t) + \vec{a}(t + \Delta t)}{2} \Delta t$$

Comment: The point was to introduce corrections to naively projecting forward. All good solvers will do that now. I might have chosen Runga-Kutta as the example, but that’s me…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is found in the sentence you omitted that immediately follows the shortened form:

> Note, however, that this algorithm assumes that acceleration $\vec{a}\left(t+\Delta t\right)$ only depends on position $\vec{x}\left(t+\Delta t\right)$ and does not depend on velocity $\vec{v}\left(t+\Delta t\right)$.

For gravitationally interacting systems, the force depends only on the position so that the shortened form can be used easily enough. But if you are dealing with a velocity dependent force (e.g., [drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)); cf also [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/240475/25301), among others), then the shortened form cannot be used because $\vec{a}\left(t\right)=f\left(t,\,x\left(t\right),\,v\left(t\right)\right)$ and incrementing to $t+\Delta t$ leads to some complications that are more easily resolved using the split step mentioned first.

Comment: Oh I though the sentence was about  'Velocity Verlet' as a whole and not just about the shortened form. But I can simply use the velocity of the step before just like in the programmed c++ algorithm below if the time steps are sufficently small, right?

Comment: No, the sentence is about the shortened form because if the acceleration depended on the velocity, then the $a\left(t+\Delta t\right)$ depends on $v\left(t+\Delta t\right)$ as well. Ignoring the intermediate velocity by using smaller time steps may work over a shorter timescale, but note that it'll take longer to integrate due to the naive $\mathcal{O}\left(n^2\right)$ summation of forces (best case would be like $\mathcal{O}\left(n\log n\right)$, I think).

Comment: I think really Step #3 in the kick-drift-kick form should read, "*Compute $a\left(t+\Delta t\right)$ from the forces using $x\left(t+\Delta t\right)$ and $v\left(t+\Delta t/2\right)$.* In this way, it would be more clear that in the shortened form, we are able to reduce it because there is no dependence on $v\left(t+\Delta t/2\right)$.

Comment: The split method is not a substitute for Velocity Verlet in the case of forces depending on velocity. Although formulae are explicit, the local error on velocity is order $\Delta t^2$ instead of $\Delta t^3$. In the case of forces depending on velocity, the generalization of Verlet's algorithm is the Groot-Warren algorithm (Groot, R. D., & Warren, P. B. (1997).  The Journal of chemical physics, 107(11), 4423-4435 ) with their parameter $\lambda=1$. It provides $\Delta t^3$ local error again.