Numerical Solution of the circular restricted three body problem
I am trying to numerically solve the differential equations in the planar circular restricted three-body problem. In the rotating frame, the differential equations are given by
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \ddot{x}&=2\dot{y}+x-\frac{(1-\mu)(x+\mu)}{s_1^3}-\frac{\mu(x-1+\mu)}{s_2^3} \\
        \ddot{y}&=-2\dot{x}+y-\frac{(1-\mu)y}{s_1^3}-\frac{\mu y}{s_2^3} 
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
where the non-dimensional  distances are given by
\begin{equation}
    s_1=\sqrt{(x'+\mu)^2+(y')^2+(z')^2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad s_2=\sqrt{(x'-1+\mu)^2+(y')^2+(z')^2}
\end{equation}
I have converted this to a set of ODE's and I am using scipys solve_ivp, here is the code
mu = 1.2151e-2
def dSdt(t, S):
    x, v_x, y, v_y = S
    return [
        v_x,
        2 * v_y
        + x
        - ((1 - mu) * (x + mu)) / ((np.sqrt((x + mu)**2 + y**2))**3)
        + (mu * (x - 1 + mu)) / ((np.sqrt((x - 1 + mu)**2 + y**2))**3),
        v_y,
        -2 * v_x
        + y
        - ((1 - mu) * y) / ((np.sqrt((x + mu)**2 + y**2))**3)
        - (mu * y) / ((np.sqrt((x - 1 + mu)**2 + y**2))**3),
    ]

x_0 = 0.8372 - 0.1
v_x0 = 0
y_0 = 0
v_y0 = 0
S_0 = (x_0, v_x0, y_0, v_y0)

t = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.001)
sol = solve_ivp(dSdt, (0, 2*np.pi), y0=S_0, method='DOP853', t_eval=t, rtol=1e-13, atol=1e-14)

However, I am not very confident in the subsequent plots and when i compute the Jacobi constant (constant of motion in the problem) given by
$$
C=-(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2)-2\tilde{U}
$$
where $\tilde{U}$ is the effective potential
$$
\tilde{U}=-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)-\frac{(1-\mu)}{s_1}-\frac{\mu}{s_2}-\frac{1}{2}(1-\mu)\mu
$$
I get a standard deviation of $0.038$ over a single period of the primaries which is orders of magnitude higher than the specified tolerance. The plot below shows the discrepancy:

I am unsure as to how I can get rid of this error and I don't really feel that I can trust the plots I get when it seems to be inaccurate. I have tried using the different schemes provided by solve_ivp, changing the tolerance and step sizes but nothing seems to help. It also seems very odd that I am getting such a large error as the code I am using is very similar to what this guy does in this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeXEPHzJqQQ&list=PLUeHTafWecAXDF9vWi7PuE2ZQQ2hXyYt_&index=11 around the 36 minute mark. He doesn't get anywhere close to the error that I am getting. Here is the code for determining the Jacobi integral:
def jacobi_integral(position, velocity):
    s_1 = np.sqrt((position[:,0]+mu)**2+(position[:,1])**2)
    s_2 = np.sqrt((position[:,0]-1+mu)**2+(position[:,1])**2)

    effective_potential = (-1/2)*((position[:,0]**2+position[:,1]**2))-(1-mu)/s_1-mu/s_2-((1-mu)*mu)/2

    jacobi_constant = -((velocity[:,0])**2+(velocity[:,1])**2)-2*effective_potential

    return jacobi_constant

I have looked into symplectic integration schemes, but they don't seem applicable from my limited understanding since I have velocity-dependent terms in my differential equations. If anyone has any tips or suggested solutions, I would greatly appreciate any input!

He used analytical expressions; the kind of integration he is doing is a lot more involved than what you are doing, and so I think you are somewhat not expected to get to how good his code would be, if you do it this roughly. However, it seems like he does show his code, so why not copy from what he showed?

I answered a question ages ago about a velocity-dependent force (specifically on quadratic drag) that may be of use to you: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/239621/25301

Have you checked out Runge-Kutta methods? Apparently they are very good for doing reasonably accurate and fast simulation of interacting gravitational bodies.

@KDP the method DOP853 is an 8th order Runge-kutta method.

I am a bit unsure of what you mean naturallyIconsistent. From my understanding he is working in Matlab and is using ODE78 which implements a type of Runge-kutta method.  He shows the function he passes to this method around the 44 minute mark which is just the same differential equations that I am using.

Thanks for the tip Kyle Kanos, I will check it out

It seems that there is a typo here, the formulas for $\ddot{x}$ in the text, where there are two minus signs, and in the code, where there is only one minus sign, are different.

Well, I'm an idiot. thank you, Gec! That definitely fixed the problem the standard deviation is of the order of the tolerance and the plots make a lot more sense now.
