# Numerical Solution and Reference System

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, computational-physics, projectile, drag

I'm trying to solve projectile motion using 2D Runge-Kutta method. The friction coefficient (in units of mass) is given by

$$ B_2/m= C + \frac{D}{1+\exp[ \frac{v^* - v_d}{\Delta}]} $$

where $D=0.0039$, $C=0.0058$, $v_d=35 m/s$ and $v^*$ is the velocity of the projectile respect to the air frame

I understand that the equations of motion that I have to solve are

$$\frac{dv_x}{dt}= - \frac{B_2}{m} \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2} \cdot  v_x \quad \quad \frac{dx}{dt}=v_x $$
$$\frac{dv_y}{dt}= - g - \frac{B_2}{m} \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2} \cdot v_y \quad \quad \frac{dy}{dt}=v_y.  $$

The problem is that I'm not sure about the relation between $(v_x, v_y)$ and the components of $v^*$, because I don't have the velocity of the  air in the Earth frame to compute the velocity of the  projectile in the Earth frame and make a relation between it and the air frame

Comment: What does $v_d$ represent?

Comment: @Nick In the exercise they say nothing about the physical meaning of that value. I assumed that it was just any value obtained from the adjustment of the coefficient of friction to that law. Do you think this value is the velocity of the air frame?

Comment: 2D quadratic drag was also considered in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28931/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.

Comment: The wind speed and direction should be an input data. None can give the answer but the author.